# How do I get label with checkbox to work?

Tags: html

I made a label because I wanted to apply `css` to the checkbox.
However, the label is not working except for the checkbox whose id is 'checkall'.

```
<div class="divCenter cartDiv">
            <ul>
                <li class="selectallforcart">
                    <div class="hanadiv">
                        <input type="checkbox" id="checkall" class="check" value="0"/>
                        <label for="checkall"></label> selelct All
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <% ArrayList<LikePdVO> likeList = (ArrayList<LikePdVO>)(request.getAttribute("likeList"));
            for(LikePdVO vo : likeList) {
                String arr[] = vo.getPhoto().split("\\*");
                %>
            <div class="cartProduct" id="<%=vo.getPd_id()%>">
                <div class="fl cartCheck">
                    <input type="checkbox" class="check" name="<%=vo.getName()%>"
                    value="<%=vo.getOrder_price()%>" id="<%=vo.getPd_id()%>">
                    <label for="<%=vo.getPd_id()%>">
                    </label>
                </div>
```

this is my code.

```
.cartDiv input[type=checkbox] + label {
        display: inline-block;
        width: 20px;
        height: 20px;
        border: 2px solid #bcbcbc;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    .cartDiv input[type=checkbox]:checked + label {
        background-color: #866744;
    }
    .cartDiv input[type=checkbox] {
        display: none;
    }
```

And this is CSS.

Comment: im sorry for my bad English i mean the second line from the bottom '<label for="<%=vo.getPd_id()%>">
                    </label>' is not working

Comment: Because the label does not have any text. try this: `<label for="<%=vo.getPd_id()%>">
test </label>`

Comment: it's not working either.....

Comment: check the input id  and `for` attribute of the `lable` in inspect part of the browsers and see  if the are the same? press `ctrl + shft + I` in chrome browser and see the html in `Element` tab

Comment: it was exactly same. It worked before, but suddenly it doesn't work, I don't know why

Comment: May be you have duplicat `id` in your data. Can you show me value of `ArrayList<LikePdVO>`?

Answer (score 1):

When you mean that the label is not working, I assume you mean that clicking on it doesn't cause the checkbox to be checked?

Either way, the label's text needs to be within the element, so it should be:

```
<label for="checkall">Select all</label>
```

And your other labels contain no text, so the label itself is probably quite small, despite the CSS, and therefore not clickable.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set label text in the label tag not out side of it.

```html
<div class="divCenter cartDiv">
        <ul>
            <li class="selectallforcart">
                <div class="hanadiv">
                    <input type="checkbox" id="checkall" class="check" value="0" />
                    <label for="checkall">selelct All</label> 
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```